# Profanity Galaxy S2 Jelly Bean

Tags: swype, dictionary

I don't know what's changed and I cannot figure out how to set it up but my S2 no longer lets me swear.

I have to manually type in the words every time, it doesn't seem to be updating any dictionaries anymore, it used to just fine before the update to Jelly Bean.

My default keyboard is Swype.

No matter what I do checking Swypes dictionary is always "(empty)"

Comment: Apparently this can be fixed by reinstalling Swype but it appears you're not able to uninstall Swype anymore ...